# Animate a self-solving rubik's cube

Tags: animation, physics, shape-keys

I am trying make a cube scene in which the cube will interact with ground while solving itself. I'm giving link to a real video, in case you are wondering how the scene might look. https://youtu.be/xCoH2AORcEQ

I am trying to recreate this scene, but the problem is in order to do so I need rigid body physics to be applied to the rubiks cube. The way others animate rubiks cube is they work with separate 27 cube to do the animaton. But in my case the rubiks cube has to be one single object, other wise physics won't work properly. So I can't animate in the tradtional way. So I tried another way. And that is, I modeled the rubiks cube in seperate 27 cubes and merged them with (ctrl+J). This time I tried shape keys instead.

And here is another problem, as you know shape key rotation is weird. It shrinks down objects in midway. So the animation became weird and I failed again. But still what I want is possible via shape keys. Yet in this case I have to set 90 shape keys (each to turn the cube 1 Degree) just to flip the cube 1 time. And a normal rubiks cube solve takes around 35 flips. That means I need around 3000 shape keys.

Again I have to animate those individually. So far this is the only way I could find. So I need your your help. Can I do something,  so that those 27 cubes act as a single object in physics but are actually different..?  Or Is there any thing I am missing?

Comment: imo its easier, to keyframe animate the part you would use rigid body physics for. Its way easier to fake the motion instead of figuring out how to animate the cube in one single object to make physics work. Animating a Rubik’s cube composed of 26 small cubes isn’t all that hard.

Comment: I didn't quite get the answer @bstnhnsl. More description will be helpful...

Comment: This wasn’t supposed to be an answer. I’m just saying, I don’t think your approach is the easiest way to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

One method:

- Add a cube
- Scale it to the size of your Rubik's Cube
- Parent the Rubik's Cube to the new cube,
- Run the physics simulation on the new cube
- In the outliner, click on the camera icon [image: camera icon] next to the new cube to disable it in renders.
- You can also go select the object properties icon [image: orange square] and under *Viewport Display* and *Display As* choose *Bounds* so that it doesn't cover up the Rubik's Cube but is still selectable.
  [image]